# How to make hover property "(mouseover)" from angular work?

Tags: angular

When I hover(mouseover) the button nothing happens, but if I Press the button hover method works.
Seems to me hover property does not work.

I have tried to do it also in CSS, but I have same problem.

I'm making xRM web app. Using Angular 6.1.1

```
<div class="right-icons" (mouseover)="over($event)">
    <mat-icon (mouseover)="over($event)" 
    class="icon-pointer" 
    (click)="onCloseButtonClick()">close</mat-icon>
</div>


   over(e) {
     console.log('test_hover');
     }
```

I expect that while hover on a button it will show me some log in console

Comment: It should work as expected. Can you maybe provide a fiddle ?

Comment: can you create a demo on stackbitz.com?

Comment: its working fine

Answer (score -1):

the solution was simple. I just closed the webTools in Chrome. and it start working.
It kinda strange, because when WebTools is open – it does not work...